# Running git filter manually

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout, git-filter

I have a repository that contains a [filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) (clean and smudge) which replaces tokens with paths (e.g. `@ROOT@` with the repository root).
However, when doing a fresh clone, the filters are (of course) not set up yet, so after cloning, I need to add the filters to the git config of the repository.

The files, however, still contain the tokens because the smudge filter is not run. The only workaround I found was removing the files and checking them out freshly, this causes the smudge filter to run. Is there another non-hacky way to run the smudge filter?

Comment: Untested: `git read-tree --reset -u HEAD` or `git checkout-index -f`. If the latter works, it's probably the one to use.

Comment: @torek None of them work, do you have another idea?

Comment: Nothing offhand. The Git code around this has changed a bunch recently (for making git-lfs efficient), so I'd hesitate even to pull a rabbit out of the source, as it were. Hm, maybe do one `read-tree --reset -u` of the empty tree, followed by a second `read-tree --reset -u HEAD`? (search SO for "git's semi-secret empty tree")